# Что такое callback URL? Из чего он состоит,

Tags: php, api, url, callback, uri

Всем привет, возникла такая проблема, мне приходят API запросы а я должен ответить на них callback-ами. Я в душе не понимаю что это такое. Может кто-нибудь помось? Прочитал пол интернета и ничего не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

callback URL - это тот адрес, который будет вызван (запрошен) после выполнения того метода API, который вы вызываете.  Например, если вы вызываете метод вот так:

```
POST /api.example.com/foo?callbackURL=http://my.server.com/bar
```

тогда, когда метод `/foo` завершается, в конце он отправляет запрос на `http://my.server.com/bar`.

Comment: Если кто-то желает, может попереводить ответы отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23347056/6104996 :)

Comment: а как должен выглядеть callback? Я должен ответить на его API)

Comment: Что значит как должен выглядеть callback? какой код внутри должен быть? Надо смотреть в документацию того API, с которым происходит работа.